# How does <a href="#"> ends up invoking Javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am an experienced backend programmer who recently decided to learn more about web development out of boredom.

I am having trouble with understanding how `<a href="#">` ends up invoking a Javascript function, or performing any action in that sense.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: I think you need to search and explore some more. This is a good place to start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Comment: The answer is: the same way any other element invokes JS functions.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - That's, erm, really helpful.

Comment: In general, through [Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event). Most user interactions relate to a specific event (`click`, `change`, etc.). Functions can be bound as *listeners* to these and, when they occurs, the listener is called.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I know it is. `;)` My comment added with the already posted answers (marteljn's) should provide enough meaning.

Answer (score 6):

Three possible ways in order of best to worst:

1. Unobtrusively - in JavaScript the `addEventListener` method is used to attach a click event handler.  This is what JQuery and other libraries are doing under the covers. In the past I believe IE used `attachEvent` instead (just as a side note).
2. `onclick` attribute of the anchor tag - `onclick="yourEventHandler()"`.
3. `href="javascript: func();"`

Comment: for 3, it'd be unlikely if it was `href="#"`.

Comment: @alex yeah I know I was just listing the three possible ways to attach event handlers.  `onclick` is also out based on his markup.

Comment: One more: `element.onclick = function(){}`

Comment: @bfavaretto true, but I would file that as a variation of unobtrusive.

Answer (score 1):

Lets break it down like this.

You first give your `href` element an ID.

`<a href="#" id="myID">My Link</a>`

Now this element can be uniquely identified.

The JavaScript to access events on that element would look like this:

```
// first get the element by id
var myLink = document.getElementById("myID");

// add an event listener to listen for clicks

myLink.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      alert(e.target.id);
      // prevent the element from invoking its default event,
      // which, in this case would be appending an '#' to the URL
      e.preventDefault();


}, false);
```

Here is an [example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/NwyRP/4/show/)

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere else in the client-side code, a javascript event handler was bound to the click event of the anchor (A) element. It's done in a separate file (or in a `script` block) as a way to separate concerns -- keeping structure (HTML), layout (CSS), and logic (Javascript) independent of each other.

The `href="#"` is a bit of a NOOP, telling the browser to not load a different page, and is a stopgap measure in case the javascript handler didn't get assigned (I.e. if the client doesn't support javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely in a case like this `a` element has `onclick` attribute that references a JavaScript function e.g.

```
 <a onclick="my function()" href="#">Click me</a>
```